# Changing tick frequency for x-axis in a two y-axis with imported data from .csv

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yaxis, xticks

Hello I'm importing my data from a .csv file and plotting it in a graph with two y-axis. The x-axis are Timestamps and I'd like to have less of them, since it looks really clutered (new here and can't post pictures yet).

I tried using **plt.xticks(df.Time[::6], rotation=45)**, as I did before with a one y-axis plot, but it doesn't work. Can someone please give me options?

My data are 3 columns, basically like this:

```
'Time':['00:09:00', '00:19:00','00:29:00', '00:39:00','00:49:00', '00:59:00',...'22:59:00'],         
'Sensor1': [16,14,12,11,10,9,...27],
'Sensor2': [159.34,158.19,159.31,155.94,158.88,154.75,...897.25]
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('.../example.csv', delimiter=';')

#get data
x = df.Time
y1 = df.Sensor1
y2 = df.Sensor2

#create a figure
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

#plot axes
#plot y1
plt.plot(x,y1,color='red',label='Sensor1', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8, marker='.', markersize=10)
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.ylabel('%')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(df.Time[::6], rotation=45)

#plot y2
#create twin axes
ax2=plt.gca().twinx()

plt.plot(x,y2,color='blue',label='Sensor2', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8, marker='.', markersize=10)
plt.ylabel('ppb')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted :D it appears it had something to do with the order in which I put the things. Now it looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('.../example.csv', delimiter=';')

#get data
x = df.Time
y1 = df.Sensor1
y2 = df.Sensor2

#create a figure
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

#plot axes
#plot y1
plt.plot(x,y1,color='red',label='Sensor1', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8, marker='.', markersize=10)
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.ylabel('%')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

#plot y2
#create twin axes
ax2=plt.gca().twinx()

plt.plot(x,y2,color='blue',label='Sensor2', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.8, marker='.', markersize=10)
plt.ylabel('ppb')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(voc_tt.Zeit[::6])

plt.show()
```